# QlikView: Adapting Bar Chart

Tags: qlikview

I have made the following chart:
[image]

The dimensions are:

1. Quarter
2. Scenario

The meassure is: Sum(Sales)

The question is: how can I make that when a user clicks on a bar on a same chart that the sales distribution per REGION is showed. In that case, I would have the same meassure, but the dimension should change to display only REGION (for the selected quarter and scenario)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TEQy8JuMpp0

Comment: I did create a cyclic group which contains Scenario and Region (in this order). When I drill down -> from the initial chart i select a Quarter, Then I select Scenarion, then I indeed come to sales distribution by Region. However, if I then go Drill-UP, I can only come one level above -> from Region to Scenario, but I cannot come to the initial chart that contains the Quarters as well. How can I resolve that?

Comment: OK try this: https://community.qlik.com/thread/33693